# Entity Framework 6.1 Slow on 'Cold Start' Only When Running in Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, entity-framework-6, azure-web-roles

While I found that EF Code First is known to be slow on cold starts after following many suggestions I have my cold start time down to about 2 seconds locally. I actually have a very simple 6 table\model DbSet.

Using an on-prem database and after deploying my app to a web role my cold start goes to about 10 seconds. All queries and actions after the initial start, while slower then running local, they are perfectly acceptable.

I've enabled EF logging and see that it takes about 3.5 seconds from DbContext class instantiated until I get the 'Opened connection...' log entry. The next EF log entry is for my first SQL statement getting ready to execute which occurs about 5 seconds after the 'Opened connection...'.

I can understand the 3.5 seconds to open a connection from the cloud to on-prem  (local connect speed is .5) but the next 5 seconds, which is .6 local, is the big unexplained hit. I have precompiled views and even tried Database First version but the 5 second gap is always there.

Anyone else experiencing this cold start hit only in Azure.....any ideas?

Comment: I'm getting kind of the same thing using Azure Web Apps. First query is really slow - sometimes is takes over 10 - 15 seconds (on a fairly simple model with very little data). The problem is that this happens multiple times. I think that Azure Web Apps get recycled (I am using "Always On") or something which causes EF to go cold again.